# Read delegate from view controller in tab bar application

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I found several posts online stating that I could access my application delegate object from any view controller through the following call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] delegate];
```

(For instance: [data between Views UIApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407678/data-between-views-uiapplication), [iOS - Calling App Delegate method from ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082738/ios-calling-app-delegate-method-from-viewcontroller))

However, whenever I include this line in a function in one of my view controllers, the application crashes.

This is the first application that I'm writing, and I cannot see the difference between my code and how other posts have said I should be using this sharedApplication call.  For completeness, below is an excerpt from my application delegate and view controller.

FirstViewController.h:

```
@class wStreamAppDelegate;
#define URL_ADDRESS @"http://google.com"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView  * webView;
wStreamAppDelegate* appDelegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) wStreamAppDelegate* appDelegate;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "wStreamAppDelegate.h"

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize webView,appDelegate;
@class wStreamAppDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSString* urlAddress = URL_ADDRESS;
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest * requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    self.appDelegate = (wStreamAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] delegate];

    //This doesn't work either
    //  wStreamAppDelegate *appDelegate= (wStreamAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] delegate];
```

wStreamAppDelegate.h:

```
@interface wStreamAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
   UIWindow *window;
   UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

If anyone has any thoughts on what may be going wrong, general advice for debugging problems like these, or tips, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: To start, go to Run >> Console to open the console and see what specific error is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly:

[Session started at 2011-11-11 22:38:37 -0800.]
2011-11-11 22:38:39.032 wStream[647:207] +[UIApplication sharedApplicaton]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1ea2898
2011-11-11 22:38:39.036 wStream[647:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIApplication sharedApplicaton]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1ea2898'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: Try this...
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] delegate];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typos get everyone sooner or later... in this case, you wrote "sharedApplicaton" instead of "sharedApplication".

Comment: That was exactly it.  Thanks for the response.  I'm accepting your answer now.